# not sure why inserting element doesn't work when condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for i in range(0,len(lst)):
    num = lst[i]
    if num == entry:
        lst.insert(i+1, elem)
    else:
        i += 1
    return lst
```

edited code but I don't know why it's inserting element when num and entry is equal.

[image]
if im understanding correctly 7 should insert when for loop iterates and encounters 5 in the list

Comment: Read up on Python for loops. `i` is not an *index*, it is an *element of the list*.

Comment: Please include all relevant information (complete error traceback, ...) as text in the question itself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see your question is not according to SO standards and you already got some downvotes. Also your previous question was already closed. You might want to take the [tour] and study [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your questions and get more positive feedback from the community. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

replace `for i in lst`: with `for _ in lst:`
You are getting this error as you are overriding the variable **i** with list element.

Answer (score 0):

`for i in list` iterates over the **elements** of the list, **not** the indices. So if you lst is:

```
lst = [10, 5, 12]
```

then:

```
for i in list:
    print(i)
```

```
10
5
12
```

You also should avoid modifying a list while you're iterating over it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change `for i in lst:` to `for e in lst:`. Where `e` is one element of the list `lst`.